# Renaming file, single character

Tags: rename, mv

Is there a shorter way to rename a file when you only want to swap out one character?
Essentially, I'd like to rename `alex_is_my_best_pan.txt` to `alex_is_my_best_pal.txt` without having to type:

`mv alex_is_my_best_pan.txt alex_is_my_best_pal.txt`, which is pretty tedious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` you can use brace expansion:

```
mv alex_is_my_best_pa{n,l}.txt
```

The `{n,l}` causes the whole word to be repeated twice, once with `n` and once with `l` in that position, and in the given order.